# create ManyToMany relation or an array of movieId in laravel 5.2?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am going to create a website which has exactly same as [IMDB.com](http://IMDB.com) site logic.

I have `lists` table that can have lots of movies from `movies` table. now I want to know which method is the best choice?

1. Creating a `ManyToMany` relation between `lists` and `movies` table and create a pivot table to store *ids* from both tables.
2. In `lists` table create a field named `movieId` and store all movies ids like an array in this field and separate them with ','.

Please let me know what way would you choose and why?

Comment: what's the purpose of list table?

Comment: the list table contains watchlist and custom lists that user can create them and add movies to each list. exactly same as imdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Go for `ManyToMany` Relationship. `Eloquent` already has the mechanism to handle this relationship reducing your effort of writing code. Defining the proper relation via pivot table will make you much more easier for handling CRUD operation too.

With the second approach you won't be able to handle this using `Eloquent`.And again this is not the standard way of creating relationship between tables. Besides you have to manually prepare the name of the movies separated by comma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a bit of concern regarding scalability of this approach. Lets say we got thousands of users and each user got multiple lists and each list consist of hundreds of movieIds. Wouldn't be any issue down the road?

Comment: Well that depends on how you handle it. Eloquent is already aware of that too. In the second approach you'll definitely be doing something manually for that number of record. Imagine if there has to be a loop how many time you are going to iterate?